# What is the parameter "animated" in functions like "viewDidAppear(_:)"?

Tags: swift, animation, uikit, lifecycle

What does the parameter `animated` in this code mean:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    /*code*/
}
```

I know the value is passed to the superclass, but what is the effect of it being true or false?

Comment: See the docs: "If YES, the view was added to the window using an animation".

Answer (score 4):

When you do:

```
self.presentViewController(UIViewController, animated: Bool)
```

You can specify if the presentation transition will be animated or not. When the presentation occurs, the presented viewController's `viewDidAppear:` will be called with `animated`, indicating if the transition was animated. It's useful if you want to do some stuff only if the transition is animated (or not), for example fade in some views after transition.